# Navigate with argument in Compose

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have to navigate with argument clientId to another compose screen.

I have in my  Screen:

```
  object ClientsListScreen : Screen(route = "clients_list_screen")

    object ClientDetailsScreen : Screen(route = "client_details_screen/{clientId}") {
        fun routeWithClientId(clientId: String): String {
            return "client_details_screen/{$clientId}"
        }
    }
```

SetupNavGraph:

```
composable(route = "${Screen.ClientDetailsScreen.route}/{clientId}") { backStackEntry ->

            val clientId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(CLIENT_ID)

            ClientDetailsScreen(
                navController = navController,
                clientId = clientId!!
            )
        }
```

ClientItem :

```
    .clickable {
  navController.navigate(Screen.ClientDetailsScreen.routeWithClientId(client.id.toString()))}
```

And ClientDetails Screen:

```
@Composable
fun ClientDetailsScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    clientId: String
) {
   Text(text = "DETAILS, $clientId")
}
```

I got this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request  NavDeepLinkRequest{
uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/client_details_screen/{ } cannot
be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0)
startDestination={Destination(0x7a02aac9) route=clients_list_screen}

What is causing this error, something with ClientListScreen ?
ClientId will never be null or -1 or something else

Comment: `Screen.ClientDetailsScreen.route` is already the route you need, no need to add `/{clientId}` one more time

Comment: See also https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

Screen:

```
object ClientDetailsScreen : Screen(route = "client_details_screen/{$CLIENT_ID_KEY}"){
      fun passClientId(id: Int): String {
         return this.route.replace(oldValue = "{$CLIENT_ID_KEY}", newValue = id.toString())
        }
    }
```

SetupNavGraph:

```
composable(
            route = Screen.ClientDetailsScreen.route,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(CLIENT_ID_KEY) {
                type = NavType.IntType
            })
        ) {

            ClientDetailsScreen(
                navController = navController, clientId = it.arguments?.getInt(
                    CLIENT_ID_KEY
                )
            )
        }
```

ClientCardItem:

```
  .clickable {
       navController.navigate(route = Screen.ClientDetailsScreen.passClientId(client.id))
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).